# Javascript function argument is not showing in Asp.Net MVC RouteValueDictionary?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new bee to Asp.net. I like to pass an id of an entity to edit method in controller through view. Here is my code.

#

```
@model IEnumerable<Login.DAL.tabLogin>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="work_area">
</div>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Username
    </th>
    <th>
        Password
    </th>
    <th>
        Email
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:editUser(@item.UserID)">Edit</a>|
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function editUser(idval) {
    alert(idval);
    $('#work_area').load('@Url.Action("Edit","Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = idval}))');
}
</script>
```

I did not get the correct functionality .

```
$('#work_area').load('@Url.Action("Edit","Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = 1}))');
```

If I hard code the id value as above , It is working as expected. Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting the correct functionality? What's happening in your current code when you click edit?

Comment: It will pass the respective record to edit method and the content will be ready for edit. For that I am passing id of current record. It should get updated in the div 'work_area'. I hope I explained correctly..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're mixing Razor and JavaScript and don't have an understanding of what happens where/when. The line of code:

```
$('#work_area').load('@Url.Action("Edit","Home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = 1}))');
```

will render as a completed URL before the javascript is rendered. That means, once the page is loaded by the browser, that line already says:

```
$('#work_area').load('http://example.com/home/edit/1');
```

and will never change based on javascript. To get the javascript parameter into your URL, you'll have to combine the URL from Razor with a javscript parameter. Try something like:

```
function editUser(idval) {
    alert(idval);
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit","Home")';
    $('#work_area').load(baseUrl + '/' + idval);
}
```

Comment: Instead of 1 can't we pass the function parameter?

Comment: @arockia you cannot access a javascript variable (function parameter) in razor code, because Razor is executed server side, and javascript is executed client side, after the Razor execution is complete. See my code edit to store the Razor-rendered URL into a javascript variable and appending the `idval`